# unique count within delimited string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, unique, delimiter

I am looking at healthcare data and there appears to be a data quality issue (outside of my control) whereby some investigation codes get listed more than once (across the various investigation positions - eg `[investigation1]`). To combat this I want to count each investigation code only once (given that each investigation can only happen once).

There are 24 investigation fields (`[investigation1`] to [`investigation24]`) and I am concatenating them all in to a long string with delimiters and using `ISNULL` to ensure an output (where the investigation might be null). Each row is a new patient attendance. Sample part of this:

`([Investigation_1] + '|' + ISNULL([Investigation_2],'') + '|' + ISNULL([Investigation_3],'')`

Examples outputs becomes:

```
01|12|05||||||||||||||||||
05|24|05|05|07||||||||||||||||
```

In the top example, I'd like to be able to report 3 unique investigations. In the bottom example, this would also be 3 (not 5). Expected current output is 175,000 rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Give us more sample data please.

Comment: Well, the first thing you should do is not use a delimited string. Sql server has a data type suited for keeping multiple data parts - it's called a table.

Comment: Did you think about unpivoting the columns, so you will reveive one row per investigation id and patient? Afterwards you could do a simple select count distinct...

Comment: user6167440 > thank you! unpivot works well.. hadn't thought of using that